# How to override *i++ for c++ custom iterator?

Tags: c++, iterator, std

This is making me quite confused, I'm implementing a custom iterator and I read here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/InputIterator, that the behavior of `*iter++` should first use the dereference operator, and then increment the returned value (which is copied), by 1.

I have in my custom iterator overriden both `operator*` and `operator++(int v)`, the problem is that `operator++(int v)` is called before `operator*` when I execute `*iter++`, which is the correct behavior, but not for what I want to do (I guess?).

If you read the link, you'll see that in the table, on the last row, it is said that if you execute `*iter++`, your implementation should first dereference, and then increment the result, which is not what is the default behavior.

I can't really seem to know what to do, any ideas?

**After understanding the answer, the title is misleading, sorry!**

Thanks,

Johan

Comment: It IS the correct behavior

Comment: @PaoloM First of all, I'm a C++ beginner so let me just apologize for that in advance. What is the correct behavior? What my code does or what the website says? They do different things, as stated in the question.

Comment: The correct behavior is that `operator++` gets called before `operator*`. It's the standard operator precedence.

Comment: Yes @PaoloM, the question is how to change that, sorry for being unclear.

Comment: You cannot change operator precedence, and even if you could, you certainly should not.  That would lead to horribly misleading code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the link that you provided, `*i++` is equivalent to:

```
value_type x = *i; // (1)
++i;               // (2)
return x;          // (3)
```

That is,

1. Dereference the iterator `i` and store it in `x`
2. Increment the iterator
3. Return the value `x` obtained by dereferencing *before* incrementing the iterator.

This can be used in template code that accepts input iterators, like this:

```
template <typename InputIterator, typename T>
InputIterator drop_until (InputIterator i, T const & x)
{
    while (*i++ != x);
    return i;
}
```

An implementation of this behavior usually looks like

```
struct my_iterator
{
    // ...

    value_type operator * ()
    {
        // return the value that this operator is pointing to
    }

    my_iterator operator ++ (int)
    {
        my_iterator copy = *this;
        // increment *this iterator
        return copy;
    }

    // ...
};
```

This works, because `i++`, which calls `operator++(int)`, returnes the previous iterator value, which then gets dereferenced, while `i` itself gets incremented.

To increment the dereferenced value, you should manually indicate operators precedence:

```
(*i)++;
```

Since this is how operator precedence is defined in the C++ standart, you cannot achieve this behavior for the expression `*i++`, or `i` would stop being an iterator, I guess.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm starting to feel dumb... How do I implement so that `*i++` gives the behavior you listed? I understand that I can indicate operators precedence on a statement, but how do I make that the default?

Comment: @JohanS which behavior? The one in the beginning of the answer?

Comment: @JohanS `operator*` and `operator++` are obviously _2_ different operators therefore you can't control the behavior of `*i++` by _fixing_ your implementation of `operator*` or `operator++`. It's the onus of the caller of these operations to specify the order they prefer.

Answer (score 1):

> If you read the link, you'll see that in the table, on the last row, it is said that if you execute *iter++, your implementation should first dereference, and then increment the result

The order of the operations is not relevant for the result. The site is not saying that the operators must be called in that order, just that the side effects must be equivalent. The example on the site is simplified. Following has equivalent side effects but also has the same order of operations as a real implementation of those two operators would have when calling `*iter++`:

```
const It it_copy = i; // copying the iterator is part of post increment
++i; // increment is called first
value_type value = *it_copy; // dereference second
return value;
```

The result will be the same.

You cannot get the order shown in that table if you call `*iter++` but you also don't need to.